# Uniformly convergence of power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I know when r is radius of convergence of power series

Power series is uniformly converge on Any closed interval of (-r , r)

I want know when power series converges on (-r , r] , [-r,r] or [-r,r) each case can include each endpoint of interval as a uniformly convergence domain?

Answer (score 3):

In [these notes](https://math.byu.edu/~bakker/M341/Lectures/Lec31.pdf), Abel's theorem is given in the form

Theorem $6.5.4$: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges at $x=R>0$, then the power series converges uniformly on $[0,R]$.  A similar result holds when the series converges at $x=-R<0$.

The proof is given in an appendix, and is too long to include here.  I'm not familiar with Abel's theorem in this form.  I know it as asserting that if the series converges at an endpoint, then the limit function is continuous as $x$ approaches the endpoint from inside the interval of convergence.  I felt that Abel's theorem, in the form I know it, was the key to the proof, but I couldn't do it.  I'll have to read this proof.

Anyway, the answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: thanks for your answer. i already knew abel"s thm. i dont know that thm can be applied this situation,

Comment: @yongseok The theorem addresses your question precisely.  Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: What i know is named abel's thm about uniformly convergence of sequence.

Comment: @yongseok And doesn't it say that the answer to your question is "yes"?  Doesn't the theorem I quoted in my answer say that the answer to your question is "yes"?  I fail to see why you think it doesn't apply.

Comment: You misunderstand my comments. Cause my english is very bad. abel's thm what i said(not in your quoted note) is considering about convergence of functional sequence seemingly. And l saw your answer and quoted notes. I understand that why abel's thm what i know and abel's thm what you quoted have same name. (They have same proof process partly)I just want you to know i very appreciate for your answering.

Comment: @yongseok Okay, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Not your fault. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you need to test those functions individually, as when deriving the formula for convergence radius, we used Cauchy's test, which is
$$\limsup _{n \to \infty} a_n ^{\frac 1 n} = c$$
1) If $c \lt 1$ the series converges
2) If $c \gt 1$ the series diverges
3) If $c = 1$ the test is **inconclusive**

Therefore there are examples where a power series converges absolutely or conditionally at both end point, conditionally at one and diverges at one, or diverges at both.

However if a power series is convergent on a end point, it is converges uniformly there.

**Proof** **(WARNING: see comments)** Suppose that this is not true. Without losing generality, suppose that a power series is convergent on $x_0+r$, but is not uniformly convergent.

Since it is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of $(x_0-r,x_0+r)$, this means that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, the series is uniformly convergent on $[x_0,x_0+r-\epsilon]$.

Therefore it is not uniformly convergent on $[x_0+r-\epsilon,x_0+r]$, which means for some $\epsilon^* \gt 0$, there is no such a number $N \gt 0$ such that as long as $n \gt N$, for all $x \in [x_0+r-\epsilon,x_0+r]$, $\lvert F_n(x) - F(x) \rvert \lt \epsilon^* $.

Therefore for all number $N \gt 0$, there is some number $x^* \in [x_0+r-\epsilon,x_0+r]$, such that $\lvert F_n(x^*) - F(x^*) \rvert \gt \epsilon^*$.

Now let $N = 1, 2, 3, ...$ and we will get a list of $x^*_1, x^*_2, x^*_3, ...$. The collection $\{(x^*_i,x^*_{i+1})\}$ is a open covering of $[x_0+r-\epsilon,x_0+r]$, since the latter is compact, by applying Heine-Borel theorem, we can conclude that the power series is not convergent at $x_0+r$, which is a contradiction. $\square$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP is assuming converge at one or both endpoints.  He wants to know about *uniform* convergence.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you. Would you think that the edited version will answer the question?

Comment: I don't understand why $\{(x^*_i, x^*_{i+1})\}$ is a cover, nor why the Heine-Borel theorem implies divergence at $x_0+r$.  I don't say you're wrong, just that I don't understand.  Let me say, however, that Abel's limit theorem is an immediate consequence of this, and it usually has a much more intricate proof, so I'm suspicious.

Comment: @saulspatz I thought that "A collection H of open sets is an open covering of a set S if every element in S is in a set H' belonging to H", and that we can make $x_i$ as close to $x_0+r$ as we please, so that any point in $[x_0+r-\epsilon,x_0+r]$ can be contained in some set in H... Maybe I did not get it right (as I am only self learning)

Comment: @saulspatz For the latter part, I thought that since we can get finitely many open set to cover the interval, it implies for some finite N the endpoint will get covered, and that means $F_n(x_0+r)-F(x_0+r) \gt \epsilon ^*$ so it diverges...

Comment: For each $i$, we will have $x_i=r$, because the series converges uniformly on compact  subsets of $[a,r)$.  Therefore, you don't get an open cover.  Nice try, though.  Look at the proof of Abel's theorem in the notes I cited in my answer, and you'll see that this is a lot more delicate.

Comment: thanks for your kindness answer i learn many things

Answer (score 0):

In order to find whether or not the power series is uniformly convergent on $[-r,r)\\$ or $(-r,r]\\$ or $[-r,r]\\$ you need to find that if the series is convergent at the end points i.e. $\sum a_n(-r)^n\\$ or $\sum a_nr^n\\$ or both are convergent respectively.

This way you can include an end point to the interval of uniform convergence.

I hope it helps : )